# How to count process time of VB6 exe inside a periodically timed VB.NET Windows Service?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I'm pretty new to VB.NET and would like to get your ideas on this topic. If I set a 5000 millisecond timer in my Windows Service to run periodically but if I add a VB6 exe to run inside the application using `System.Diagnostics.process.start` command then will the Windows Service program automatically wait until the VB6 exe runs and stop it's process?

As an example let's say I set the Windows Service timer event for 5000 milliseconds(5s) and now I just started it and 5000 milliseconds counting. But inside the Windows Service there's another VB6 app starting and there's no time calculation(that I'm aware of) how long it'll take to run and finish that process. In that case will the Windows Service wait or freeze it's 5000 millisecond timer until the VB6 app executes and finish? Or else how would that work? Also is there any code that I can get the execution time of the VB6 so that I can write an IF condition to wait until the VB6 program finish it's thing and then finish the Windows Service?

Hope the question is clear, Thank you!

Comment: If you read the MSDN documentation on `System.Diagnostics.Process` you will find several members that will assist with what you are trying to do.  Make sure you're reading the documentation for the version of .NET that you are using, because there are members (most notably `WaitForExitAsync`) that are not present in all versions of the framework.

Comment: Thank you very much @Craig I think that's what I've been looking, WaitForExit(). Much appreciated!

Comment: Beware that `WaitForExit` is a blocking call (that is, the your service will stop everything until the process exits).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, to stop everything in Windows Service until the VB6(exe) does it's thing and exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start won't block the timer from continued execution.

Comment: Thank you, so do you mean that it does not matter I have 5000 milliseconds timer already running since the Windows Service will hold or pause the timer until the VB6 exe executes and end the process?

Comment: @EDMT I'm assuming that you have ONE timer and it is spawning the process.  If that is true and you aren't waiting the process then the timer code will continue immediately after the .Start.